# Boost: Wait until worker thread waits on a condition variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

### Situation

I've got a worker thread that's being triggered by a `condition_variable` to do some work. Basically it is working very good and as supposed.

### Problem

However there's one problem: The thread launching the worker thread may get a long enough time slice to feed the data queue and notify the `condition_variable` *when the worker thread is not ready yet*, i.e. when it didn't reach the `condition_variable.wait()` line yet.

Is there any way I can wait for a worker thread until the first call to `wait()` is made so it's guaranteed that work *will* be processed when I notify the worker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to do that. When the worker thread is ready, it will do the work. It won't need to be triggered by a condition variable because it won't ever wait.

Waiting for something that has already happened is a coding error. If you might ever even think of doing that, you fundamentally don't understand condition variables.

Before a thread waits on a condition variable, it *must* make sure that there is something it needs to wait for. That thing *must* be protected by the mutex associated with the condition variable. And when the thread returns from the condition variable wait, it usually must re-test to see if it needs to wait again.

Comment: I see, but isn't it how it's often designed? I.e. launch X workers that wait for work and process it when it arrives? Regarding your explanation I shouldn't have any workers launched until there is work, then launch them, right?

Comment: You can launch the workers whenever you want. One of two things will happen: 1) There will be no work for a worker when it launches, in which case it should wait for work. 2) There will be work for a worker when it launches, in which cause it should not wait for work. (Just don't wait for something that has already happened. Make sure you need to wait, under the protection of the mutex, before you block on the condition variable.)